# How can I make an HTML Login Page that redirects to another page on Google Sites?

Tags: html, authentication, google-sites-2016

I have a Google Sites public page but I also want to have a members area for the staff, where everyone can login. I've tried using 3rd party services (AuthPro) but I'm having trouble with getting it to work. I want to make a login page in HTML which redirects to another page hidden from navigation.

I found a template for an HTML Login Page and embedded it in my website, but it goes to 'invalid resource' since I don't know how to redirect in HTML.

Here is the template:

````
<head>
<title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="loginForm" method="post" action="login.php">
<table width="20%" bgcolor="0099CC" align="center">

<tr>
<td colspan=2><center><font size=4><b>HTML Login Page</b></font></center></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Username:</td>
<td><input type="text" size=25 name="userid"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Password:</td>
<td><input type="Password" size=25 name="pwd"></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td ><input type="Reset"></td>
<td><input type="submit" onclick="return check(this.form)" value="Login"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</form>
<script language="javascript">
function check(form)
{

if(form.userid.value == "Roseindia" && form.pwd.value == "Roseindia")
{
    return true;
}
else
{
    alert("Error Password or Username")
    return false;
}
}
</script>

</body>
</html>```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can add the attribute target in this line of code like this

```
 <td> input type="submit" onclick="return check(this.form)" value="Login" target="_blank" </td>
```

I am not sure it works for your example, but it does work on the  `<a>` tag. You can give it a shot.